# How to add form validation to a joomla module

Tags: joomla, module, server-side-validation

I'd like to know if there's a way to add custom form validation to a module in joomla 3.7. I want my customer to be able to fill in two date fields [start] and [end] in the module administration. But I can't find a proper way to check something like "both fields are optional but if one field is filled in the other one must be a valid date too". I know I can do this with a Joomla component, but I'm coding a module here.

I've also read about coding and copying custom validation rule files to the administrator folder, but this feels a bit "dirty" to me because a module should work right after installation and be update-safe furthermore.

So my question is: Does anyone know a "proper" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server sided validation you can use a custom validation rule.

[Joomla's documentation tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Server-side_form_validation) show it for a component but you can modify it for use with modules, without losing any future update ability:

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic" addrulepath="modules/mod_module/rules">
            <field name="field" rule="dualdate" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Then you would create your custom rule class in the module's `rule` folder:

```
class JFormRuleDualDate extends JFormRule
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul, this looks promising. However this only shows how to validate a single field. But how can I get two fields at once in the test() function to validate/compare them? Or can I merge two fields with a separator to become one?

Comment: The `test()` function passes the `$form` object as its 5th parameter. You may be able to use this to get & check the data from the other paired field, perhaps with `$form->getData()`?

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction, Paul. Thanks again. For all who encounter the same problem with subforms: I had to set the addrulepath attribute to the fieldset containing the subform field (NOT the form in subform.xml). The validate="subform" attribute must be set in this field too instead of setting validate="date" in each field of the subform itself.
What you get in your test() method as $value parameter is an OBJECT containing all subform fields which you can iterate over.

Comment: This looks something like this then:
<field 
name="mysubformfield" 
type="subform" 
label="News" 
formsource="modules/mod_news/subform.xml" 
multiple="true" 
layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table" 
validate="subform" 
/>

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help-ish :)

Comment: One more question: Is there a way I can change the values in the test function somehow before they get saved? I tried to overwrite $value but that had no effect on the result.

Comment: You may be able to use the `$form` object to call `$form->setValue($name, $group = null, $value = null);` but if that doesn't work you're entering content plugin territory really. See [onContentPrepareData](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentPrepareData) and [onContentAfterSave](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentAfterSave) for the before and after events.

Comment: My trials to change data in JformRule were not successful. Seems if you really need to process module form data BEFORE saving, you can do that implementing a plugin, at least I managed to do it that way thanks to Paul's last hint. Because of the fact that this is another topic, I've posted my solution here:
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20842/how-to-change-form-values-sent-by-a-module/20853#20853